# Reading from file into Array

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have a file with numbers. It looks as follows:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

The problem occurs while reading the numbers into Array.

Here is a piece of code:

```
Scanner file1 = new Scanner( new File("file1.txt") );

int lengt_h = 0;

// Here Eclipse crashes...
while( file1.hasNext() ) lengt_h++;

int[] numberArray = new int[lengt_h];

for(int i=0; i<numberArray.length; i++) {
        numberArray[i] = file1.nextInt();
}

for(int n: numberArray) System.out.print(numberArray[n] + " ");
```

Even if I change  a hasNext() function into constant length (e.g 10), then numbers in numberArray Array looks as follows:

```
1 1 1 2 1 1 5 5 1 3
```

Why the code does not work properly?

Comment: Eclipse crashes, or your program doesn't make any progress? You should read the documentation for `Scanner.hasNext()` to see what is happening there.

Comment: `hasNext()` merely tells you if there is anything waiting for you in the file. It doesn't actually move past that number. So you have an endless loop there.

Comment: You have an infinite loop because `hasNext()` always return `true` since you only keep checking if the next token exists but you never actually read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. problem with you code is you are not moving the `Sacanner` pointer in `while loop` so it were infinite loop.
2. In your last `for` loop you are trying to access element from `numberArray[n]` which is wrong because `n` itself is a number from your array `numberArray`.

you can try this :

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner file1 = new Scanner(new File("d:\\data.txt"));
        int lengt_h = 0;
        while (file1.hasNext()) {
            lengt_h++;
            file1.next();
        }
        file1 = new Scanner(new File("d:\\data.txt")); // again put file pointer at beginning
        int[] numberArray = new int[lengt_h];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
            numberArray[i] = file1.nextInt();       // read integer from file
        }
        for (int n : numberArray)
            System.out.print(n + " ");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while( file1.hasNext() ) lengt_h++; // infi loop
```

**hasNext** method returns true if and only if this scanner has another token

```
public boolean hasNext()
```

You are not reading next token and hence `hasNext()` will always return true

**[EDIT]**

If you don't know the size of array in advance, its better to use `ArrayList`

**[1]** http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_arraylist.htm

Answer (score 0):

Check the hasNext method here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29

it says "The scanner does not advance past any input."

So to move it further you should move to next token.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<Integer> numberArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (file1.hasNext())
    numberArray.add(file1.nextInt());
for (Integer n : numberArray)
    System.out.print(n + " ");
```